# Azure Key Vault limits

Tags: azure

We are developing authentication service (using identityServer) and we want to sign the JWT token returned to the user with private key stored in Azure Key Vault HSM

Our domain consists of millions of users that expected to call the authentication service once an hour in average (and therefore the key vault)

According to Microsoft docs the key vault service limits is 100 calls per second. See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-service-limits/

Are we using Azure Key Vault as we suppose to do? It seems that the Key Vault transactions volume is very low.

Comment: Something is strange in this scenario. You have millions of user authentications per hour? If yes then you may need multiple vaults, or contact Microsoft as suggested in Michael's answer.

Comment: Why do you find this scenario strange? It's a mobile app, every time the user calls the backend he need to do it with an outh token. The IdentityServer supplies tokens to the user (signed by the keyvailt) with expiration time of an hour

Comment: Not exactly strange, just uncommon. Sounds like a mega product with such large user base. BTW, what happens after 1 hour? Will the application ask the user for credentials again (password, pin number, etc)?

Comment: If the token is expired, the next call to the backend will claim a new token

Comment: You get a new access token using an existing refresh token, right? Do you really need to sign each access token with an HSM key? I think it should be enough to sign just the long-lived refresh tokens with HSM key. The access token can be signed with your own key, which by it's turn is signed by the HSM key as Michael suggets.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/key-vault/) there is a footnote that says -

> contact Microsoft for pricing for operation volumes exceeding 50 million operations per month

The alternative is to use Key vault as a key signing service, so you have a key that is signed by the key in key vault, that is rotated amongst your servers. It would be an extra piece of work, but it means that you can have very short lived certificates, which could provide a little additional security.